# "only const val can be used in constant expressions" compile time error Dagger2 Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Unable to build project to create the dependency Injection. I successfully built it in Java but on converting each file to Kotlin (really intrigued now...) project doesn't build as there is a compile time error

"Only 'const val' can be used n constant expressions 
  Unresolved reference: ApplicationModule 
  An annotation argument must be a compile time constant"

Understandable to the right Kotlin developer this would be a no-brainre what to change but its left me very confused.

As the ApplicationModule won't import I cannot build the project.

ApplicationComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(application: MyApplication)

    @get:ApplicationContext
    val context: Context

    val networkService: NetworkService

    val databaseService: DatabaseService



}
```

ApplicationModule

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(private val application: MyApplication) {

    @ApplicationContext
    @Provides
    internal fun provideContext(): Context {
        return application
    }

    @Provides
    @DatabaseInfo
    internal fun provideDatabaseName(): String {
        return "dummy_db"
    }

    @Provides
    @DatabaseInfo
    internal fun provideDatabaseVersion(): Int? {
        return 1
    }

    @Provides
    @NetworkInfo
    internal fun provideApiKey(): String {
        return "SOME_API_KEY"
    }
}
```

[image: Error]

https://github.com/BenMohammad/DaggerAppKotlin

Comment: Maybe you need `::class.java` instead?

Comment: @Zoe `::class` is required by `module`.. `::class.java` is compiler error

Comment: can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss the package line in your Application module file.

put this line `package com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.module`
 at the top of your ApplicationModule file